# ffmpeg only outputs at bit depth s32p when converting from flac to alac

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert some audio files from FLAC to ALAC (m4a) using `ffmpeg`. For my environment (Apple & Sonos), the *lowest common denominator* seems to be as follows:

> ALAC (.m4a) encoding at 44.1kHz, & bit depth = 16 bits

The problem I'm having is that the output file produced by `ffmpeg` has a **bit depth of '32p'**; i.e.  `sample_fmt=s32p`

I've done the conversion with several sets of arguments, but the results are the same. I've been unable to find anything that explains why this might be. Here's one of the commands I've tried:

```
$ file='01 Jubilee.flac'
$ ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec alac -ar 44100 -sample_fmt:0 s16 -c:v png "${file/%.flac/.16.m4a}"
```

I've run `ffprobe` on the **input file** to determine its format:

```
$ ffprobe -i "$file" -show_streams
```

Which (in summary) yields:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 176400 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 450x446 [SAR 72:72 DAR 225:223], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```

... and on the **output file**:

```
$ ffprobe -i "${file/%.flac/.16.m4a}" -show_streams
```

Which (in summary) yields:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 44100 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit), 1564 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 450x446 [SAR 1:1 DAR 225:223], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)  

[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=alac
codec_long_name=ALAC (Apple Lossless Audio Codec)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=alac
codec_tag=0x63616c61
sample_fmt=s32p
sample_rate=44100

... 

etc, etc
```

I've posted only a small snippet of the `ffprobe` output, but can provide all of it if needed. Also, my `ffmpeg` version:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version git-2020-01-13-7225479 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
```

Finally, here's the output of the `ffmpeg` conversion above:

```
$ ffmpeg -v info -hide_banner -i "$file" -acodec alac -ar 44100 -sample_fmt:0 s16 -c:v png "${file/%.flac/.16.m4a}"
Input #0, flac, from '01 Jubilee.flac':
  Metadata:
    track           : 1
    TITLE           : Jubilee
    ARTIST          : Bill Charlap Trio
    album_artist    : Bill Charlap Trio
    ALBUM           : Stardust The Music Of Hoagy Carmichael
    DATE            : 2003
    GENRE           : Jazz
    TRACKTOTAL      : 11
    disc            : 1
    DISCTOTAL       : 1
    ALBUM ARTIST    : Bill Charlap Trio
  Duration: 00:02:23.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6176 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 176400 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 450x446 [SAR 72:72 DAR 225:223], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
File '01 Jubilee.16.m4a' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> alac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x10dc6b000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[ipod @ 0x7fc3a1002200] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, ipod, to '01 Jubilee.16.m4a':
  Metadata:
    track           : 1
    TITLE           : Jubilee
    ARTIST          : Bill Charlap Trio
    album_artist    : Bill Charlap Trio
    ALBUM           : Stardust The Music Of Hoagy Carmichael
    DATE            : 2003
    GENRE           : Jazz
    TRACKTOTAL      : 11
    disc            : 1
    DISCTOTAL       : 1
    ALBUM ARTIST    : Bill Charlap Trio
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(progressive), 450x446 [SAR 1:1 DAR 225:223], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.103 png
    Stream #0:1: Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 44100 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit), 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.103 alac
frame=    1 fps=0.8 q=-0.0 Lsize=   27745kB time=00:02:23.22 bitrate=1587.0kbits/s speed= 113x    
video:396kB audio:27342kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.026342%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here.

```
ffmpeg -i in -c:a alac -ar 44100 -sample_fmt s16p -c:v png -vsync 0 out.m4a
```

Note that ALAC encoder checks if the raw frame is 16-bit *planar*

Comment: Ah! I did not realize that ALAC used `planar` encoding (s16p, s32p). Still it seems that the `s16` option would provide `ffmpeg` with enough of a clue to 'do the right thing' given that it knows the conversion is to ALAC. But in any case, this seems to have resolved the issue as Sonos now plays it.

Comment: The user supplied `-pix_fmt` or `-sample_fmt` is taken as a directive rather than a hint.

Comment: Not sure I agree that it's taken as a directive... it defaulted to `s32p` when the argument was `s16`. The files played in every music app I have except Sonos. Just sayin'...

Comment: Share the full log of your original command and I can tell you why.

Comment: That would be very helpful! I've edited my Q to add that at the end. If a higher `loglevel` than `info` is needed to get the relevant data, pls advise.

Comment: The option is specified as `-sample_fmt:0 s16` but the first output stream is the image, so it is ignored. Since, effectively, no format has been set for the audio output stream, ffmpeg selects s32p as the input audio is s32

Comment: OK... but: `ffprobe -i "$file" -show_streams` => `Stream #0:0: Audio:...` & `Stream #0:1: Video:...`. This is the **input** stream of course, but later the `Stream mapping` log entry appears to **reverse** that!? Why did that happen?

Comment: Encoding options apply to output streams and the stream mapping identifies that order. If the command has `-map` , then the order of maps decides output stream order. If not, it's always video, audio, subtitles.

Comment: Does that mean that my input file was encoded in a "non-standard" order? Or is this something peculiar to `ffmpeg`?

Comment: No, input stream order is decided by a combination of format constraints and input demuxer behaviour. For an MP4, the encoding order will be the track order. For audio-only formats, even if the video was designated as first stream by ffmpeg, it's an ancillary piece of data so the demuxer will treat the main content (audio) as the first stream.